# Appropiate Design Pattern to track metrics with Dropwizard

Tags: java, design-patterns, dropwizard, metrics, code-cleanup

I am researching about Dropwizard Metrics, my goal is to measure counters and histograms in real time, sending them to an ElasticSearch instance.

Even I have found easy to make it work at development stage, I wonder if there is a way to add Metrics code as the project grows while keeping it clean.

Is there a commonly used Design Pattern when tracking metrics? I mean, an implementation that could let us mantain our code decoupled, business from metrics.

The possible approaches I have been considering are:

A) AOP: Clean, but still some code in my business classes.

B) HTTP Proxy and forward requests to an specific microservice/API, with Camel or similar tool. Maybe too sophisticated, and I am afraid that could add latency.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your post and explain your current approach, how you grow, where your concerns are etc. This question is very open and the answer would probably fill books.

Comment: @pandaadb Thanks, I have added two possible approaches. We are building a social game with massive requests, and measuring needs to be done without producing dirty code.

Comment: What does Elasticsearch have to do with your question? Do you want to use metrics and then report the metrics to elasticsearch? Do your results have to be immediate? (e.g. realtime seeing what is happening?) What are you measuring? (requests? Execution time of code? Counting something ...?)

Comment: @pandaadb Thanks again, added some information and put more light in ES role, which is secondary and was included in the question just for context understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather confusing question. But i'll try it:

By the sound of it. you are doing things in a weird way. Metrics already has it's own best practise and since you are measuring business logic, if you want to have it in detail, I don't see how you can not put code in your business class. E.g., you will always need to submit that to your metrics anyway, something like this:

```
try (Context time = metrics.timer(SEND_TIME).time()) {
     // do some business operations and send something 
}
```

So, the only way you would "maybe" get around it, is using interceptors. They'll just wrap your business method calls into a metric and that's that. I believe, using guice, you can intercept each and every method call you make, so basically recording everything.

That of course will make you lose details. You can only measure methods, not what is in the methods. Of course, now you can split all your methods in smaller methods and record even more details - but does that really make your code cleaner?

The typical use of metrics, the way I see it, is to have 1 registry that holds all metrics, and you inject that registry into the classes you want to measure using metrics. This approach is fine in my opinion.

The issue comes with reporting. You want to do this in real time? That means, you want each metric to submit a request to your ES instance to index whatever you just measured.

That approach has 2 problems:

1. If you make a request for every single metric you measure, you kill your application. You can make those request asynchronous, but since you don't want to loose anything, you'll still have to worry about outages, DOS, retries etc etc etc. You'll be so busy spanning threads tracking your metrics, you won't have any left to do the logic you want to measure in the first place. This sounds like a very bad idea.
2. You could use a reporter. They work asynchronously, they don't do much, they don't use up resources etc. But now you are not real time anymore. Reporters typically run every minute or so, so you'll have that delay. And yes, you can run your reporter every 10 seconds, every 1 second etc. - you'll always be not real time. And once you get small enough, depending on your implementation, you will have problem 1 again where all your application does is trying to talk to elastic search.

In case you need a reporter: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-metrics-reporter-java

So essentially, I am slightly confused by your approach, but then again I never really had to do real time reporting.

We use near-realtime reporting, which means, we have a maximum delay of 1 minute which is fine for us and our customers. This is how often we can shift the data from the application to the reporting hosts without compromising application performance.

I am reading that you can use the ES client impl, that talks directly to the cluster rather than using http requests to index your data. That might give you some more performance, but I believe 1 and 2 still hold.

I hope that helps,

Artur

Comment: Thanks, I was talking about what you are naming near-realtime, have been trying the ES-Reporter and works fine. 
I am not experienced using neither interceptors (great to hear about Guice, never tried it before) nor AOP, so I'm looking for opinions from people that have already implemented them. Found helpful your answer in that way.

Comment: Well, with dropwizard, there is: https://github.com/xvik/dropwizard-guicey I use this in production across multiple servers and it makes my life super easy. In addition you get out of the box support for guice interceptors: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AOP All guice created classes can be intercepted like that, and you will be able to basically write one class that can intercept everything and measure all of it. Make sure to read the limitations as well. Spring has more capabilities with regards to interceptors.